# Haskell and Erlang Map Function

Tags: haskell, dictionary, erlang

What is the different between erlang map function and haskell map function ?

in **erlang** map ->  `M1 = #{name=>john,age=>25}`.

in **Haskell** map ->  `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

Comment: That's not the map function in Erlang, that's the map data structure.

Comment: can you please explain erlang map data structure @Dogbert

Answer (score 7):

In **Erlang**, the [`maps`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html) are **data structures**, you store *values* in it you associate with *keys*. It works like a *dictionary*. Erlang however has a [**`map` function**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#map-2):

> ```
> map(Fun, Map1) -> Map2
> ```
>
> Types:
>
> - `Fun` = `fun((K, V1) -> V2)`
> - `Map1` = `Map2` = `#{}`
> - `K` = `V1` = `V2` = `term()`

Like @Pascal says in his answer, the `map` function is defined on various data structures (arrays,...).

The `map` in **Haskell** you describe is **not a data structure**, it is a function to **transform a *list* of elements into another list of elements**. This is done in a lazy manner. Mind that here `map` thus works on a specific data structure: the list `[a]`. Although this might change in the future.

The two have not much to do with each other. They share a name, because "mapping" usually means that you project values on other values.

Comment: To complete Willem answer, erlang provides the map function for various data structures: for maps  as already mentioned and also for arrays, dicts, gb-trees, lists, orddicts.